# Leave out default Logstash fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, field, logstash

After processing data with: input | filter | output > ElasticSearch the format it's get stored in is somewhat like:

```js
"_index": "logstash-2012.07.02",
"_type": "stdin",
"_id": "JdRaI5R6RT2do_WhCYM-qg",
"_score": 0.30685282,
"_source": {
    "@source": "stdin://dist/",
    "@type": "stdin",
    "@tags": [
        "tag1",
        "tag2"
    ],
    "@fields": {},
    "@timestamp": "2012-07-02T06:17:48.533000Z",
    "@source_host": "dist",
    "@source_path": "/",
    "@message": "test"
}
```

I filter/store most of the important information in specific fields, is it possible to leave out the default fields like: @source_path and @source_host? In the near future it's going to store 8 billion logs/month and I would like to run some performance tests with this default fields excluded (I just don't use these fields).

Answer (score 7):

This removes fields from output:

```
filter {
    mutate {
        # remove duplicate fields
        # this leaves timestamp from message and source_path for source
        remove => ["@timestamp", "@source"]
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of that will depend on what web interface you are using to view your logs.  I'm using Kibana, and a customer logger (c#) that indexes the following:

```js
{
  "_index": "logstash-2013.03.13",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "n3GzIC68R1mcdj6Wte6jWw",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": 
  {
    "@source": "File",
    "@message": "Shalom",
    "@fields": 
    {
      "tempor": "hit"
    },
    "@tags": 
    [
      "tag1"
    ],
    "level": "Info"
    "@timestamp": "2013-03-13T21:47:51.9838974Z"
  }
}
```

This shows up in Kibana, and the source fields are not there.

Comment: I really don't think it is dependend on the web interface.

I'm storing data directly into ElasticSearch from Logstash, when retrieving this data via the REST API of ES it already has these fields.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude certain fields you can use [prune filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-prune.html#plugins-filters-prune-blacklist_names).

```
filter {
    prune {
        blacklist_names => [ "@timestamp", "@source" ]
    }
}
```

Prune filter is not a logstash default plugin and must be installed first:

```
bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-prune
```